# Looking for a c++ compression library/libraries that can decompress rar, 7z, bz2, zip etc

Tags: c++, 7zip, compression, rar

Not sure if a unified library like this exist or if the algorithms are even open-sourced. I Need to be able to decompress as many types as possible without having to install any other applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`7zip` has all its required functions to handle archives in a separate library and it can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/

It will handle

> 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP, WIM, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB,
>   DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM,
>   SquashFS, UDF, VHD, WIM, XAR, Z

.

Answer (score 2):

Zlib will do this all for you: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm.